# java -jar <jarFile> arguments can run multiple jar files?

Tags: batch-file, jar, apk

I try to prepare bat file to sign apk file with signapk.jar
The syntax of this program is:

```
java -jar signapk.jar testkey.x509.pem testkey.pk8 <update.apk> <update_signed.apk>
```

My script looks like this:

```
java -jar "%~dp0%\SignApk\signapk.jar" "%~dp0%\SignApk\testkey.x509.pem" "%~dp0%\SignApk\testkey.pk8" "%~dp0%\SignApk\%ApkName%.apk" "%~dp0%\SignApk\%ApkName%_sign.apk"
```

When I execute the script I receive a message "Unable to access jarfile {update_signed.apk}", java "thinks" that  is also a jar file and tries to run it..

Someone can help me how to pass arguments to jar file ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-jar` variant of the Java command line does only process a single JAR file, so your error message is not related to that.

Your error message is most likely created by the signapk application: You should try the direct command (with no batch wrapper, without the argument variables and especially without special characters or space in the path or the arguments or relative naming - do a cd into the SignApk dir first).

If that works, you can work backwards to find where the escaping has failed you.

BTW: if [this](https://code.google.com/p/signapk/) is the tool, you need to specify a sign command as well:

```
java -jar signapk.jar -c sign.pem -k sign.p8 sign your.apk
```

Comment: Is the jar file-path always the first parameter after the `-jar` option?
Are all the next parameters passing to the jar application?

Comment: yes, the syntax is `java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]`

Comment: your solution works, I just removed the full path `%~dp0%\SignApk` 
and I use `cd` instead

Comment: There are a lot of possible problems with the relative path (depending on how the application is written). It might not expect a path for the input name or similar. But in principle your approach is fine and the java program should support it (or at least better handle the errors). But its independent from the java launcher and the -jar option.